# How to rearrange array in php in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have array of array and I just need to rearrange array according to me. Here is the output of my array.

```
Array
(
    [36736] => Array
        (
            [meta] => Array
                (
                    [Closing Date] => 
                    [Technical Consultant] => 
                    [Client Name] => 
                    [Stage] => Waiting for Technical Assignment
                    [Contract Name] =>
                    [Signing Rate] => 
                    [Contract Number] =>
                    [Client Number] => 
                    [Closer Name] =>
                    [Completed On] => 2019-05-23
                    [Assigned Date] => 05/22/2019 12:28 pm
            )
        )
```

Expected output

```
Array
(
    [36736] => Array
        (
            [meta] => Array
                (
                    [Client Name] => 
                    [Client Number] => 
                    [Contract Name] => this is secod contract or abc
                    [Contract Number] => 
                    [Stage] => Waiting for Technical Assignment
                    [Closing Date] => 
                    [Technical Consultant] =>                 
                    [Signing Rate] =>
                    [Closer Name] =>
                    [Completed On] => 2019-05-23
                    [Assigned Date] => 05/22/2019 12:28 pm
            )
        )
```

Comment: Rearrange it how? What kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: Where is your array where is your output?

Comment: @quickSwap here is my code, please check.

Comment: @tshimkusb plese check now.

Comment: Where is your code? I only see two array dumps without any further explanation of the difference between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo link**](https://3v4l.org/RK4dT).

You can achieve by creating custom order key array you want,

```
$keys = ["Client Name", "Client Number", "Contract Name", "Contract Number", "Stage", "Closing Date",
    "Technical Consultant", "Signing Rate", "Closer Name", "Completed On", "Assigned Date"];
foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) { // & defines changes will be reflected at its address in memory
    $value['meta'] = array_replace(array_flip($keys), $value["meta"]);
}
```

Comment: sir i have one more array look at here.
[meta] => Array
                (
                  old array mention in question.
                  )
[static] => Array
                (
                    [created_by] => 1
                    [created_time] => 1558508302
                    [modified_by] => 
                    [modified_time] => 
                    [record_status] => 3
                )

Comment: i don't want to change static array.

Comment: @Akshay I made changes as per your requirement, once check my answer now.

Comment: its working for meta array. But i need my array back in same format.
like:-
meta()